# Optimal way to upgrade stores

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade

Dear community I currently upgrade my magento store manually, by replacing my files with the newer versions files manually using FTP (coda).

Has got me through many upgrades but is rather long winded. Thus, I was wondering if anyone could recommend a more suitable way to upgrade a magento store.

I know the different ways. i.e, connect manager but that is not a suitable way.

Looking at magento download site for the latest version (1.9.3.7) I see the ability to download a .diff file, which I believe checks differences from my version and new version and applies the changes.

https://pasteboard.co/GVXdOns.png

I was hoping someone could kindly elaborate further on this, like what is different between the .diff and .sh files of each of the relative patches. i.e, SUPEE-10415?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to put your site into some sort of source control. (like GIT).

You can use Github.com for example.

Once your current code is in source control you can now take new versions of Magento and copy your updated files into your original source.

So for example:

You commit everything to your repo (all steps are not listed here)

Once you have everything there confirm you have a clean master branch

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

You have everything in GIT under your master branch, you will then create a new branch (To test)

Call it 1.9.3.7

```
$ git checkout -b 1.9.3.7
Switched to a new branch '1.9.3.7'
```

You can then take your new source code and copy into your new version

```
rsync -avz /downloaded/code/magento/ /site/your/src/

commit -am 'Add 1.9.3.7 files'
```

You can test the above

Once that is confirmed working you can merge your branch to master and promote to live!

Always do this on a development site

Comment: Version control systems is not an option at the moment sadly